# symfony2 validate one of two form fields is not blank

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

what's the simplest way to add a validator which checks that one of two form fields is not blank?

```
    $builder
        ...
        ->add('file', 'file', array(
            'constraints' => array(
                new NotBlank(array('message' => "...", 'groups' => array('order step 3'))),
                new Image(array('maxSize' => '1M', 'groups' => array('order step 3')))
            )
        ))
        ...
        ->add('fileName', 'hidden')
```

I need to check if whether 'file' or 'fileName' is not empty

Comment: I don't know if a way exist to check "if this field is empty but not this".Otherwise following the [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) you can try to test your `PRE_SET_DATA` and add your own logic.

Comment: You can use the Callback constraint, then check in it if one of the fields is not empty.